# Mac OS X command-line tools - differences from FreeBSD

Tags: command-line, osx, freebsd, gnu, compatibility

As I understand it many Mac OS X command-line tools (like `ls`, `cp`, `chmod`, `chown` etc.) are imported from FreeBSD.

- Which version of FreeBSD contains the command-line tools most compatible with the OS X ones?
- What are important differences?
- Are some of the tools imported from different systems (NetBSD, GNU...)?

My intention is to build a free environment which would contain command-line tools closest to Mac OS X for testing simple shell scripts behaviour in Mac OS X like environment. The filesytem structure, devices or other aspects do not need to be similar.

Answer (score 5):

You probably want to run some variant of [Darwin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darwin_%28operating_system%29), probably [PureDarwin](http://www.puredarwin.org), rather than FreeBSD.

Comment: Thank you. I know that PureDarwin exists but at least for the beginning I would prefer something with a wider community sacrificing the level of compatibility. In this phase probably the best would be to be able to compile the command-line tools on Linux.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say the OSX tools are closest to the OSX tools. They are open source, you can download the source directly from Apple:

http://opensource.apple.com/

Comment: Thank you :) Do they compile without problems on FreeBSD?

Comment: Right now I am trying to compile some tools on Linux but I am missing some header files like [`membership.h`](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22membership.h%22+site%3Aopensource.apple.com). I hope that on FreeBSD I will be more successful.

Comment: Yes, I imagine they'd be more likely to compile with FreeBSD.